# Is SQL Server Data Tools a paid product of Microsoft or a Free Product?

Tags: sql-server, license, sql-server-tools

I don't find an evidence in Microsoft Pages regarding SQL Server Data Tools Licensing and Price details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Here all the instructions to download and install SQL Server Data Tools and no term mentioning it is Licensed.

As I understand searching for such details are to up to our responsibility but I didn't get a clue for it. So my question is SQL Server Data Tools is Free or Not? If Free then Shall we simply download and install as instructed in the below link? If Paid, where is the pricing details?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is free and a part of Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do we need to Install VS or we shall directly install SSDT(We don't have VS already installed in the Server)?

Comment: If you just install SSDT it will install a minimal version of Visual Studio.

Comment: It is up to you. Behind the scene in both cases are Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The EULA of VS 2019 community edition has a specific section that allows enterprise users to use it for the SSDT workload. See https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/.

> Any number of your users may use the software only for Microsoft SQL Server development when using the SQL Server Data Tools or the extensions “Microsoft Analysis Services Projects”, “Microsoft Reporting Services Projects”, or “SQL Server Integration Services Projects” to develop Microsoft SQL Server database projects or Analysis Services, Reporting Services, Power BI Report Server, or Integration Services projects.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/1886